# what does verbose = __debug__ mean in following code?

Tags: python, genetic-programming, deap

```
from deap import tools
from deap import algorithms

def eaSimpleWithElitism(population, toolbox, cxpb, mutpb, ngen, stats=None,
             halloffame=None, verbose=__debug__):
    """This algorithm is similar to DEAP eaSimple() algorithm, with the modification that
    halloffame is used to implement an elitism mechanism. The individuals contained in the
    halloffame are directly injected into the next generation and are not subject to the
    genetic operators of selection, crossover and mutation.
    """
    logbook = tools.Logbook()
    logbook.header = ['gen', 'nevals'] + (stats.fields if stats else [])

    # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
    invalid_ind = [ind for ind in population if not ind.fitness.valid]
    fitnesses = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
    for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit

    if halloffame is None:
        raise ValueError("halloffame parameter must not be empty!")

    halloffame.update(population)   ## Updates the Hall of Fame with the initial population
    hof_size = len(halloffame.items) if halloffame.items else 0   ## Determines the size of the Hall of Fame

    record = stats.compile(population) if stats else {}  ##  If a stats object is provided (i.e., it is not 'None'), the compile                                                                                          ## method is called to compute the statistics. Otherwise, an empty dictionary {} is returned.
                                                         ## The compile method takes the population as input and returns a dictionary containing various                                                                  ## statistics
                                                         
    logbook.record(gen=0, nevals=len(invalid_ind), **record) ## we saved the generation, the number of evaluations and everything contained in the record                                                                     ## produced by a statistics object using the star magic (**record)

    
    if verbose:
        print(logbook.stream)   ## This variable is a boolean flag that determines whether verbose output should be printed during the evolutionary process. If                                  ## verbose is True, it indicates that the user wants to see detailed information about each generation. The logbook. stream                                      ## attribute contains a formatted representation of the logbook, which typically includes information about the current                                          ## generation, such as the generation number, the number of evaluations, and any other statistics collected during the evolution                                 ## process

    # Begin the generational process
    for gen in range(1, ngen + 1):

        # Select the next generation individuals
        offspring = toolbox.select(population, len(population) - hof_size)  ## Selects individuals from the population for breeding, excluding those already in                                                                              ## the Hall of Fame. (but how...)????????? This expression determines the number of                                                                              ## individuals to select for the next generation. len(population) gives the total                                                                                ## size of the population, and hof_size represents the size of the hall of fame. By                                                                              ## subtracting the size of the hall of fame from the total population size, we                                                                                   ## ensure that the individuals selected for the next generation do not include that                                                                              ## already present in the hall of fame.

        # Vary the pool of individuals
        offspring = algorithms.varAnd(offspring, toolbox, cxpb, mutpb)      ## deap.algorithms.varAnd(population, toolbox, cxpb, mutpb)
                                                                            ## Part of an evolutionary algorithm applying only the variation part (crossover and                                                                             ## mutation). The modified individuals have their fitness invalidated. The                                                                                       ## individuals are cloned so returned population is independent of the put population

        # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        fitnesses = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

        # add the best back to population:                                   
        offspring.extend(halloffame.items)                                  ## Elitism occurs here

        # Update the hall of fame with the generated individuals
        halloffame.update(offspring)

        # Replace the current population by the offspring
        population[:] = offspring

        # Append the current generation statistics to the logbook
        record = stats.compile(population) if stats else {}
        logbook.record(gen=gen, nevals=len(invalid_ind), **record)
        if verbose:
            print(logbook.stream)

    return population, logbook
```

I am learning GP, and I ran into it.

Answer (score 0):

`__debug__` is a [read-only Boolean variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#debug__) set by the interpreter.

It is primarily used to disable `assert` statements at runtime; this code should probably not be using it to enable or disable logging.